# how to read txt file.?

Tags: vb6

I am reading textfile using vb6 code. My requirements are if the line starts with 6 then i need to read that line otherwise i have to leave that line and goto next line. can anyone help me how to do that?

```
if ( start pos == 6)
{
    //do
}
else
{
    //do noting
}
```

i need this help in vb6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that

```
Dim nFileNum As Integer, sNextLine As String
nFileNum = FreeFile
Open "C:\log.txt" For Input As nFileNum
Do While Not EOF(nFileNum)
    Line Input #nFileNum, sNextLine
    If Mid(sNextLine, 1, 1) = "6" Then
         'here what you want
    End If
 Loop
 Close nFileNum
```

Comment: Line Input reads line by line, you read every line, just do nothing when it starts with 6

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Const ForReading = 1 
Const TristateUseDefault = -2 

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = oFS.GetFile("yourfile.txt")
Set oStream = oFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault) 
Do While Not oStream.AtEndOfStream 
   sRecord=oStream.ReadLine 
   If Substring(sRecord, 1, 1) = "6" Then
      ' do
   Else
      ' do nothing
   End If
Loop 
oStream.Close
```